# Missing contacts in odoo chatter

Tags: odoo

We are using odoo v13. We have the following problem ...

When we type @L2k in the chatter (log note) it only shows one (the one we added last) of the contacts starting with L2k L2k (see picture).

[image].

The rest of the existing contacts (see picture) are not shown.

[image]

I tested with dfiferent browsers and settings but no idea what causes this.

Any idea?

Comment: It should bring all contacts including all types of contact. Please verify if you have any custom addons which restrict Odoo standard behavior.

Comment: We have a lot of customized modules. Could you pls. tell me which search is used for getting the contacts so we can check if we block this in our custom modules?

Comment: I found the problem. The contact shown L2k IT was linked to a user. As sson as I deleted the user it worked again. Thanks everybody for his help.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a custom module, you can check the domain in a *_name_search()* or *name_get()* method in the `res.partner` object.

To verify it, you should commented out entire method and test your desire output. If it works as per your expectation, then you need to fix domain logic.

Comment: We only have this for products ...

@api.model def _name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None): if not args: args = [] if name: positive_operators = ['=', 'ilike', '=ilike', 'like', '=like'] product_ids = [] ...

Comment: Interesting. Any *_search()* method? I tested it in my production database and other dbs. It is standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is ... odoo requires a user assigned to the partner for internal recipients.